# Python reading responses and validating the result

Tags: python

currently I am stuck with being able to print out the result gotten from the API, but not being able to alter nor read them without parsing it into a text file.

Furthermore, I wouldn't need all of the information that the API provides and would be great if I can only have the match_id.

The response from the API:[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxY29.png).

From the result I would only need the match_id and after I have gotten the match_id, I would compare it with a list of string e.g. 3238829394, 3238829395 and more, to check whether does any of the value are similar to mine, and if it's similar, the system would then alert me

I have found a way of doing it by passing the results into a text file, then comparing it with the list that I have.

The code for getting the response:

```
import dota2api
import json
import requests

api = dota2api.Initialise("[Value API][2]")

reponse = api.get_match_history_by_seq_num(start_at_match_seq_num=2829690055, matches_requested=1)
response = str(hist)
f = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
f.write(response)
f.close()
```

However I am hoping to find a faster and better way to do this process, as it is very time consuming and unstable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a JSON file back from that API. In python all data can be accessed directly without parsing it.

The response will be something like (sorry, but in that image I cannot copy paste to read the JSON properly):

```
for match in response['matches']:
    if is_similar(match['match_id']):
        do_something_cool_here
```

I think that should do what you need. If you give the answer as string I can help you building the code properly, but I guess you get the idea of what I am trying to say there :)

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

We talked by private and this works:

```
import dota2api
import requests

api = dota2api.Initialise("API_KEY")

response = api.get_match_history_by_seq_num(start_at_match_seq_num=SEQ_NUM, matches_requested=1)

match_id_check = MATCH_ID

for match in response['matches']:
    if match_id_check == match['match_id']:
        print(match)
```

with API_KEY, SEQ_NUM and MATCH_ID to configure

Comment: It returns me an error, TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: make please: print(dir(response)) and put it here

Comment: ['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'json', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'url', 'values']

Comment: then please do this: *import json* then *json = json.loads(response)* and then you have it as I said before (I think). Just for being sure, please first make a *response.__class__.__name__* and tell me what do you have as a class. If it is not a string, then we may need to do: 
*json = json.loads(str(response))* or maybe another stuff. We need to know the class of the response :)